# C++ : array of coordinates?

Tags: c++, arrays, refactoring, code-cleanup

I have a problem with my code. Actually it works, but I want to clean it to make it more proper.

So I have a class Coord which contains a float x and a float y.

The constructor is :

```
void Coord::Coord (float x,float y)
{
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
}
```

I create all the points that I need in that way :

```
Coord pt1(0,1);
Coord pt2(20,0);
...
Coord pt61(12,14); .... `
```

After I have to make an array of some points , for exemple
the fifth five points will be assigned in an array, 4 other points in another array, 2 other points in another one...

```
Coord pts_weakhealth[3] = {pt1,pt2,pt3};
```

This array, I'll have to give as arguments for the constructor of a class
for example:

```
Sef health(pts_weakhealth,3);
Sef strength(pts_weak,4);`
```

I'll create some Sef in the same way and then make an array of them

```
Sef spec[2] = {health,strength};
```

and a class universe will contains some sef :

```
Universe hlth(spec);
```

You can imagine that when I have a lot of points, a lot of sef, it's a lot of dirty code...

How can I improve that? to make my code better...

Comment: What version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: This probably belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: why are all your points not in an array? When you have pt1, pt2, pt3, ..., that's a clear sign that you need an array.

Comment: @nicoooogna : In that case, C++11 is on the table. I'll retag.

Comment: the only way to make it a bit more clean that I found :

Comment: std::vector<Coord*> test;
  test.push_back(new Coord(0,0));

Comment: @nicoooogna : Don't use pointers, they're error-prone and completely unnecessary here.

Comment: std::vector<Coord> test;
  test.push_back(Coord(0,0));

Comment: maybe that way is better then

Comment: @ildjarn I guess you don't need your coordinates for anything that has any speed eh? copy constructors flying everywhere on classes that should be POD structs are much better...especially since there is a universe class that could handle deletes of all the evil, evil pointers. get off my lawn and go program c#!

Comment: @OrgnlDave : Who said anything about speed? If _I_ was doing it, it would be with a proper ET-based polygon/geometry library. I was simply discouraging use of raw pointers. Keep your C# to yourself. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn no, I meant that discouraging pointers simply because they're pointers is C#-centric. Of course I have no idea why this fellow is storing 2d points, but having written 2 3d software renderers in my time, in addition to more maths handlers, when you're using tons of points you need to be using POD structures that are dynamically allocated and passed by reference. Of course this case may be different...

Comment: @OrgnlDave : "*I meant that discouraging pointers is C#-centric*" And discouraging use of _raw_ pointers is modern-C++-centric.

Comment: @ildjarn would be glad to continue this somewhere else...I am somewhat of an SO newb, is there any sort of private IM system?

Comment: @OrgnlDave : Yes, there's a chat system external to the comments, but I'm off for the evening. Maybe tomorrow. :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's being asked here... but here are a few suggestions that should get you moving in the right direction:

1. Don't hard-code the point initializations. Write a routine to
   read the points from a configuration or initialization file.
2. Don't store them in an array. Build vectors or lists or deques of
   points based on information in the configuration file.
3. Use the configuration file to build up your `Sef`s and
   `Universe`s from previously defined points.

Comment: thanks it's also the solution i have chosen